# How to disable auto open of Google sign in

Tags: angular

I am using the package `abacritt/angularx-social-login`

When I inject `SocialAuthService` into my constructor, Google signup automatically loads on the frontend.

How is it possible to `disable` this behaviour so I call when the `Google signup` sheet appears?

Answer (score 1):

Also using abacritt/angularx-social-login, v1.2.5. Would have used the latest but seems to require angular v15, am using angular v14.

I managed to hide this by adding following [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/toggle-display-with-cookies) article, tried a few other ways but none of them i could get working. It seemed to stop prompting as soon as I did step 1, would be interested to know if others experienced the same. Added the cookie just in case they fix that at the google end.

1. Added data-skip_prompt_cookie="ggCookie", eg:
2. Added cookie called ggCookie following [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Answer (score 1):

To prevent one click account selection popup, write GoogleInitOptions which is second parameter for GoogleLoginProvider on your module providers array.

Like this.

```
provider:new GoogleLoginProvider('aaaaaa-aaaaaaaa.apps.googleusercontent.com', {oneTapEnabled:false, prompt:'consent'})
```

For more info [click](https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login/blob/master/projects/lib/src/providers/google-login-provider.ts).